# Ambiguous request for two method in a same controller with different names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a same controller I've two actions, with the following signatures:

```
[MultipleButton(Argument = "save", Name = "action")]
public virtual ActionResult Save(SomeModel someModel)
```

and

```
public virtual ActionResult Attachments(long? Id, string Name, bool IsReadOnly, long IdCategory)
```

When I'm using the submit button (calling the method `Save`), I've an error saying that the request is ambiguous between methods **Save** and **Attachments**.

error:

> La richiesta corrente per l'azione 'Attachments' nel tipo di
>   controller 'FirstController' è ambigua tra i metodi di azione
>   seguenti:  System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   SalvaDati(xxx.yyy.Web.UI.Sun.Models.First.FirstModel) in tipo
>   xxx.yyy.Web.UI.Controllers.FirstController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Attachments(System.Nullable`1[System.Int64], System.String, Boolean,
>   Int64) in tipo xxx.yyy.Web.Controllers.FirstController

What is wrong ?

Comment: Is there another action with named "Save" ?

Comment: Can you please show some traceable code snippets?

Comment: @Rainman: no, there's only one method with that name

Comment: @Mike: which part of code do you need ?

Comment: post the full details of the error message, not a re-phrasing. Showing your controller definition, your routing config and the actual URL which was requested would also be relevant. Also why are your methods virtual? Can this controller be overriden?

Comment: posted the full error infos

Comment: Please show us your form, from which you make the call to that action.

Comment: As I requsted before, please also show the controller definition, your routing config and the actual URL which was called.